# How do I fix the error? TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'int'

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I have a task:
An array a0, a1,…, an − 1 is given. For each element, find the distance from it to the nearest zero. It is guaranteed that zero occurs at least once in the array.

Input data
The first line of the input contains an integer n (1≤n≤2⋅105) - the length of the array a. The second line contains the elements of the array, separated by spaces (−109≤ai≤109).

Output
Print the sequence d0, d1,…, dn − 1. The di value must be equal to the distance from the element at position i to the nearest zero element.

Here is my solution:

```html
n=int(input())
a=list(map(int, input().split())) 
b = [i for i in range(len(a)) if a[i] == 0]
print(*[min(abs(i - j) for j in b) for i in enumerate(a)])
```

But I get the error TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'int'.
How can I solve this problem? How to write it differently?

Comment: What do intend that: `for i in enumerate(a)` means for you?

Answer (score 1):

The function `enumerate` returns a tuple which is causing the `TypeError`. You can just keep a placeholder variable to separate the tuple into i and another placeholder variable, like this:

```
print(*[min(abs(i - j) for j in b) for i,_ in enumerate(a)])
```

Or alternatively, not use `enumerate` at all.

```
print(*[min(abs(i - j) for j in b) for i in range(n)])
```

Answer (score 0):

the enumerate function is used to get the index and the data of the list at the same time.
so enumerate gives,
for data,index in enumerate(a)